# PostgreSQL - should i only create index for the rest of columns that don't have index yet?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, multiple-columns

if table_name has 3 column (a,b,c), and I'm going to create an index with those 3 column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_name_a_b_c ON table_name (a,b,c);
```

But there's already an index of column a that I previously created :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_name_a ON table_name (a);
```

Should I create only for the other 2, or create for those 3 columns that also include column a (with above query)?

Comment: You can remove `idx_table_name_a` - any query using the index on `(a)` can also use the index on `(a,b,c)`. Whether or not you "should" create other indexes completely depends on your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Note that index considerations are only possible if you have a query. It never makes sense to index a table as such, but only to index a table for a query.

So let's assume that you have a query that would benefit from a three-column index, like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name
WHERE a = 12 AND b = 42 AND c BETWEEN 7 AND 22;
```

- The best option is to create that index and drop the existing one, because the three-column index can serve all purposes that the single-column index can (that is because `a` is the leading column in the index).

  Such an index will lead to a single index-only scan on the table, which (if you have `VACUUM`ed the table) is the most efficient way to execute the query.
- The second best option is to create the two-column index you proposed and leave the single-column index on `a`.

  Then the optimizer's strategy will depend on the distribution of values.

  - If the condition on `a` is selective enough, PostgreSQL will ignore your new index and just scan the one on `a`.
  - If the condition on `b` and `c` is selective, PostgreSQL will scan only your new index.
  - If all conditions together are not selective, PostgreSQL may choose a sequential scan of the table and ignore all your indexes.
  - If neither the condition on `a` nor the conditions on `b` and `c` together are selective, but all three conditions together are selective, PostgreSQL can opt to perform a bitmap index scan on both indexes and combine the result.